# Changing dalvik/libcore causes rebuilding the whole framework

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I'm adding some interception routines to Dalvik libcore methods (e.g. file open method in libcore/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/luni/platform/OSFileSystem.java), which I think only changes basic sharing libraries. But to my surprise, every time I run *make* after modifications, it rebuilds nearly everything of the framework, such as Calculator application, W3C DOM parser, etc. It really takes time to build the framework after a small modification. I'm wondering if it is possible to reduce number of rebuilt components after modifying dalvik libcore? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually isn't too surprising that changing core.jar causes many things to be rebuilt. core.jar contains many/all of the core java classes, like Object, String etc. So that *every* other jar/apk that gets built actually depends on core.jar.

From a makefile perspective, it has no clue what you changed in core.jar, and whether it is safe to *not* rebuild all these other things that depend on core.jar. It simply sees that the last modified time on core.jar is newer than on all of the other jars/apk that depend on it, so it rebuilds them all.

The trick, however, is to tell make specifically what you want to build, instead of telling it to build everything.

Assuming that you have already done a full build previously, you can simply do

```
make core snod
```

The core target will specifically build a new core.jar with your changes, without rebuilding anything that depends on core.jar.

And the snod target (short for systemimage-nodeps) will cause it to repackage everything from out/target/product//system into a new system.img. This is a "special" target that is declared in build/core/Makefile.

In general, the target for a particular jar/apk is simply the name of that jar/apk, without the extension. Alternatively, you can look at the Android.mk file for that module, and find the module name, which is typically something like `LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME` or `LOCAL_MODULE`, depending on the type of module.

For core.jar (in gingerbread at least), the module name is in libcore/JavaLibrary.mk (which is actually included by libcore/Android.mk). This file contains definitions for a number of different modules, but the first one, with `LOCAL_MODULE := core` is the one resposible for building core.jar. The rest seem to mostly be test related modules.

Comment: That's great! But how can I know which make arguments should I use (like 'core snod') here?

Comment: I've added additional information to the answer, in regards to your comment